# Should I git push to develop branch when merging my feature branch into develop?

Tags: git, github

Our repo has `master`, `develop`, `feature` branches.

1) I finish my development on my local `feature` branch, and I push to the remote `feature` branch (`git push`)

2) I switch to my local `develop` branch, then merge my local `feature` branch into the develop branch. (`git merge`)

3) I push my local `develop` branch to my remote `develop` branch (`git push`).

4) I then repeat steps 1) to 3) against my `master` branch.

Is this the recommended way ?

Comment: This is opinion based ;) Anyway, when using plain git it's a good approach. But I prefer using pull requests (GitHub, bit bucket, gitlab etc). Then you could have code reviews, integrated builds (and deployments) etc.

Comment: With develop and master branches, I think you're looking for "gitflow workflow".  See https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

Comment: @Julian thanks. What is the difference between what i described VS using pull requests ?

Comment: @user1008636 No difference in best-case: One does the merge locally, and the other does the merge remotely. However, you will start seeing a difference when you get conflicts (worst-case), since pull requests will terminate when you get conflicts, and the hosting server will force you to do it locally (like you did now), in order to resolve the conflict first.

Comment: You are trying to use the Gitflow Workflow, from experience no one uses it from CLI, use Git Kraken or SmartGit for instance to do it using UI in one click, easier and it keep the code clean and versionned.